# My socket.io server start disconnecting clients randomly (for a "ping timeout" reason) when many clients are connected

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

I'm building a website, where my client communicates with the server over web sockets. I'm using Nodejs on the backend and hence, the famous socket.io library for web sockets communication.

### The Problem

Everything works fine with 1 to ~ 40 clients, after that the server starts disconnecting clients randomly. at the start I thought it is a scaling problem, maybe memory or something like that. However, after an extensive debugging session, I noticed that the reason for disconnection is **ping timeout**.

### What I have tried

I searched on the internet and some people recommended increasing the pingtimeout and pingInterval options when creating the server and others recommended using the `transports: ['websocket']` option. So I tried both approaches. Here is what it looks like:

```
const io = require("socket.io");
const socketServer = io(port, {
      transports: ['websocket'],
      allowUpgrades: false,
      pingTimeout: 600000,
      pingInterval: 300000
    });
```

This worked fine for a while. I noticed that my server can handle up to ~80 clients with these configurations. However, a weird error appear when ~80 or 90 concurrent clients are connected:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I'm assuming this error occur because I'm setting `transports: ["websockets"]` but I'm not sure.

### My Goal

I want my server to handle >=1000 clients. I mean 30, 40 or even 100 clients should be not that much for a node server to handle, am I right? Besides, the socket.io library is recommended by other developers, so I guess that is not the problem.

Comment: How are you simulating 90 concurrent clients?  Are they all running in the same browser?  Also why did you set `allowUpgrades: false`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Hi thanks for checking this. I tested this with 5 friends, each one of us opened ~20 clients on his browser/computer. I don't know exactly why I set allowUpgrades to false. I know that I was searching on github and I saw someone suggesting that.

Comment: Well, it is possible that your issue is an artifact of how you were testing (trying to put 20 clients in one browser).

Comment: I also wouldn't suggest using `allowUpgrades: false` when the default is `true` and you don't know why or what it does.  I don't know exactly what that setting does myself and the doc is useless in describing it.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the hint. Yes I tried to read the docs but it was kinda hard to understand what these properties do

Comment: check this link my it help for you [link](https://socket.io/blog/engine-io-4-release/#Heartbeat-mechanism-reversal)